# Time-dependence of mass of rolling sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

I'm working on a problem for fun trying to find an expression for the mass of a sphere as it rolls off the side of an already rolling sphere (I'm assuming the top sphere is a 'snowball', meaning it collects mass as it rolls). I'm having an issue with my solution.

I used Newton's second law in terms of momentum to put the external forces on the top sphere in terms of how the mass changes. how would i make the assumption that it's gaining mass or losing mass? If it was losing mass, would I need to make the $\mathrm{d}m/\mathrm{d}t$ term negative? Am i approaching this kind of problem (where a system has variable mass) correctly?

I have the forces on the top sphere as,

$$\begin{align}
F_x &= F_f+mg\sin(θ) = ma+v\frac{dm}{dt}, \\
F_y &= mg\cos(θ)−F_N = m\frac{v^2}{R}+v\frac{dm}{dt}, \\
τ &= rF_f = Iα+ω\frac{dI}{dt}.
\end{align}$$

Additionally, does it matter which equations i use to find the mass? Like if i combined the first and last, or the first and second, would i get equivalent results?

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Comment: I understand what you're saying and i thank you for informing me. Would you suggest i re-submit this post with a question more geared towards the concepts involved rather than a 'check my work' question? Needless to say, i'm sure it's apparent i'm new to this site.

Comment: Yes, I would suggest trying to write the question to ask about the concept that is stopping you from accepting or competing the problem. Don't worry about being new, we all started somewhere.

Comment: But you're doing the right thing by editing this post - don't submit a brand new one that asks the same question. (Just in case that wasn't clear.)

Comment: I've edited the post to try and coincide with the guidelines. However, it's still on hold. Is there anymore editing necessary?